# Delete Image From Server By Clicking the Delete Button NodeJS(And Deleting The Image Name From Table)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The button is deleting the image name from mySQL table(the button is working).
At the same time, I want to delete the image from the server.

here is my `index.js`

```
document.querySelector('table tbody').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target.className === "delete-row-btn") {
        deleteRowById(event.target.dataset.id);
    }
    if (event.target.className === "edit-row-btn") {
        handleEditRow(event.target.dataset.id);
        document.querySelector('#btn').click();
    }
});

function deleteRowById(id) {
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/delete/' + id, {
        method: 'DELETE'
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        if (data.success) {
            location.reload();
        }
    });
}
```

app.js

```
app.delete('/delete/:id', (request, response) => {
    const { id, img } = request.params;
    const db = dbService.getDbServiceInstance();

    const result = db.deleteRowById(id);
    
    result
    .then(data => response.json({success : data}))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

at first you doesn't send a key `img` in the request params and I don't know why you destructing it from the request object in this line `const { id, img } = request.params;`

- You want to delete the image file from the server: I will assume that you store the image file in your server not on any external storage like S3 or whatever, that means that you need to delete a file from your file system so you can use `fs` module from Node.js to do that

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'your_directory', 'image-name');

fs.unlink(filePath, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(`Error deleting file: ${err}`);
  } else {
    res.status(204)
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm destructing it to get the image name.

Comment: But how to execute this code when i click the button

Comment: @OussamaBaroud you doesn't send the image name from the client side and you don't need it you have the ID, just get the record from the database, then access the name and delete it, - how you can execute the code?  -put the code I wrote in the `app.delete` callback function

Comment: I put the code in the callback function and used the image path: path.join( __dirname, 'img', '0829.png'). The image is not deleted when I clicked the button.

Comment: I fixed it. but how I get the record from the database, then access the name and delete it.

Comment: you can select the record by id - look the docs of the ORM/Query builder you use - and access the name of the file before deleting the record from the database

Comment: I use this to delete the record:

Comment: async deleteRowById(id) {
        try {
            id = parseInt(id, 10); 
            const response = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const query = "DELETE FROM names WHERE id = ?";
    
                connection.query(query, [id] , (err, result) => {
                    if (err) reject(new Error(err.message));
                    resolve(result.affectedRows);
                })
            });
    
            return response === 1 ? true : false;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return false;
        }
    }

Comment: How do i access the name before deleting the row